# Bullet Constraints Tool Add-On

Tags: add-on, constraints

I downloaded this add-on, but can't seem to find where to use it in any of the menus. I'm using version 2.81 of blender. Does anyone know where I can find it in version 2.81? Or does it even work in version 2.81? [image: Image of add-on in add-on menu]

It says its located in the Toolbar in the 3D view, but can't seem to find it there. I'll include a picture. Is this the correct toolbar? Or is there another one?

[image: Toolbar]

Comment: You can see in your screenshot it says "upgrade to 2.8x required". I haven't checked that specific add-on, but it probably will only be partially functional, if at all.

Comment: @RayMairlot it won't be functional at all. When Blender detects that the add-on is for < 2.80 it displays this message and won't call the register function.

Comment: I just resolved the issue by using a previous version of blender for my project.